# STL-friendly pImpl class?

Tags: c++, stl, pimpl-idiom

I am maintaining a project that can take a considerable time to build so am trying to reduce dependencies where possible.  Some of the classes could make use if the `pImpl` idiom and I want to make sure I do this correctly and that the classes will play nicely with the STL (especially containers.)  Here is a sample of what I plan to do - does this look OK?  I am using `std::auto_ptr` for the implementation pointer - is this acceptable?  Would using a `boost::shared_ptr` be a better idea?

Here is some code for a `SampleImpl` class that uses classes called `Foo` and `Bar`:

```
// SampleImpl.h
#ifndef SAMPLEIMPL_H
#define SAMPLEIMPL_H

#include <memory>

// Forward references
class Foo;
class Bar;

class SampleImpl
{
public:
    // Default constructor
    SampleImpl();
    // Full constructor
    SampleImpl(const Foo& foo, const Bar& bar);
    // Copy constructor
    SampleImpl(const SampleImpl& SampleImpl);
    // Required for std::auto_ptr?
    ~SampleImpl();
    // Assignment operator
    SampleImpl& operator=(const SampleImpl& rhs);
    // Equality operator
    bool operator==(const SampleImpl& rhs) const;
    // Inequality operator
    bool operator!=(const SampleImpl& rhs) const;

    // Accessors
    Foo foo() const;
    Bar bar() const;

private:
    // Implementation forward reference
    struct Impl;
    // Implementation ptr
    std::auto_ptr<Impl> impl_;
};

#endif // SAMPLEIMPL_H

// SampleImpl.cpp
#include "SampleImpl.h"
#include "Foo.h"
#include "Bar.h"

// Implementation definition
struct SampleImpl::Impl
{
    Foo foo_;
    Bar bar_;

    // Default constructor
    Impl()
    {
    }

    // Full constructor
    Impl(const Foo& foo, const Bar& bar) :
        foo_(foo),
        bar_(bar)
    {
    }
};

SampleImpl::SampleImpl() :
    impl_(new Impl)
{
}

SampleImpl::SampleImpl(const Foo& foo, const Bar& bar) :
    impl_(new Impl(foo, bar))
{
}

SampleImpl::SampleImpl(const SampleImpl& sample) :
    impl_(new Impl(*sample.impl_))
{
}

SampleImpl& SampleImpl::operator=(const SampleImpl& rhs)
{
    if (this != &rhs)
    {
        *impl_ = *rhs.impl_;
    }
    return *this;
}

bool SampleImpl::operator==(const SampleImpl& rhs) const
{
    return  impl_->foo_ == rhs.impl_->foo_ &&
        impl_->bar_ == rhs.impl_->bar_;
}

bool SampleImpl::operator!=(const SampleImpl& rhs) const
{
    return !(*this == rhs);
}

SampleImpl::~SampleImpl()
{
}

Foo SampleImpl::foo() const
{
    return impl_->foo_;
}

Bar SampleImpl::bar() const
{
    return impl_->bar_;
}
```

Comment: `boost::scoped_ptr` is pretty much created for this purpose. It's a much better fit than `auto_ptr` as it doesn't allow change of ownership at all.

Comment: @Rob Good point in your comment, I felt I had to delete my answer ;)

Comment: @Andreas, you were right initially, I was in the process of commenting to Rob's comment. If a constructor of `Foo` throws an exception during construction of `new Foo()`, it's not your responsibility to delete the object, it's guaranteed by the language that the memory will be freed.

Comment: @Idan K No, I was wrong actually ;) The memory for `SampleImpl` will be deleted but not memory allocated by `SampleImpl`'s constructor unless a deallocation function for the memory can be found (i.e. something like `auto_ptr`'s destructor). See standard 5.3.4/17 for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider using copy-and-swap for assignment if it's possible that Foo or Bar might throw as they're being copied. Without seeing the definitions of those classes, it's not possible to say whether they can or not. Without seeing their published interface, it's not possible to say whether they will in future change to do so, without you realising.

As jalf says, using auto_ptr is slightly dangerous. It doesn't behave the way you want on copy or assignment. At a quick look, I don't think your code ever allows the impl_ member to be copied or assigned, so it's probably OK.

If you can use scoped_ptr, though, then the compiler will do that tricky job for you of checking that it's never wrongly modified. `const` might be tempting, but then you can't swap.

Comment: If I use `boost::scoped_ptr` can I drop the empty destructor from my class?

Comment: I hadn't noticed the empty destructor, actually. What does it achieve in the current code - isn't it identical to having no destructor at all and letting the compiler generate the default? I guess the rule of 3 says you need to implement the destructor, but actually in this case I think the rule is wrong. The default destructor is fine, because you aren't actually cloning any resources in operator=, just modifying the one you've already got.

Comment: `boost::scoped_ptr` doesn't work unless I supply a destructor (I get 'use of undefined type' and 'deletion of pointer to incomplete type 'SampleImpl::Impl'; no destructor called' errors.  However, `boost::shared_ptr` doesn't require a destructor.

Comment: @Steve. Without the destructor I get compilation errors if I use `boost::scoped_ptr`.  I had it there for `std::auto_ptr` because I'm sure I once read it is required (might of been Meyers.)

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, it's to do with the default destructor being generated without a definition of Impl, whereas if you define the destructor in the cpp file, then Impl is a complete type and its destructor is visible. I don't know why shared_ptr is different, sorry.

Comment: Ah, I now know why shared_ptr is different, its because shared_ptr doesn't reference the payload's destructor in its destructor, it references it in its constructor. auto_ptr and scoped_ptr don't have configurable deallocators, so they reference the payload's destructor in their destructors. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311166/stdautoptr-or-boostsharedptr-for-pimpl-idiom

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of problems with the Pimpl.

First of all, though not evident: if you use Pimpl, you will have to define the copy constructor / assignment operator and destructor (now known as "Dreaded 3")

You can ease that by creating a nice template class with the proper semantic.

The problem is that if the compiler sets on defining one of the "Dreaded 3" for you, because you had used forward declaration, it does know how to call the "Dreaded 3" of the object forward declared...

Most surprising: it seems to work with `std::auto_ptr` most of the times, but you'll have unexpected memory leaks because the `delete` does not work. If you use a custom template class though, the compiler will complain that it cannot find the needed operator (at least, that's my experience with gcc 3.4.2).

As a bonus, my own pimpl class:

```
template <class T>
class pimpl
{
public:
  /**
   * Types
   */
  typedef const T const_value;
  typedef T* pointer;
  typedef const T* const_pointer;
  typedef T& reference;
  typedef const T& const_reference;

  /**
   * Gang of Four
   */
  pimpl() : m_value(new T) {}
  explicit pimpl(const_reference v) : m_value(new T(v)) {}

  pimpl(const pimpl& rhs) : m_value(new T(*(rhs.m_value))) {}

  pimpl& operator=(const pimpl& rhs)
  {
    pimpl tmp(rhs);
    swap(tmp);
    return *this;
  } // operator=

  ~pimpl() { delete m_value; }

  void swap(pimpl& rhs)
  {
    pointer temp(rhs.m_value);
    rhs.m_value = m_value;
    m_value = temp;
  } // swap

  /**
   * Data access
   */
  pointer get() { return m_value; }
  const_pointer get() const { return m_value; }

  reference operator*() { return *m_value; }
  const_reference operator*() const { return *m_value; }

  pointer operator->() { return m_value; }
  const_pointer operator->() const { return m_value; }

private:
  pointer m_value;
}; // class pimpl<T>

// Swap
template <class T>
void swap(pimpl<T>& lhs, pimpl<T>& rhs) { lhs.swap(rhs); }
```

Not much considering boost (especially for the cast issues), but there are some niceties:

- proper copy semantic (ie deep)
- proper const propagation

You still have to write the "Dreaded 3". but at least you can treat it with value semantic.

---

**EDIT**: Spurred on by Frerich Raabe, here is the lazy version, when writing the Big Three (now Four) is a hassle.

The idea is to "capture" information where the full type is available and use an abstract interface to make it manipulable.

```
struct Holder {
    virtual ~Holder() {}
    virtual Holder* clone() const = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct HolderT: Holder {
    HolderT(): _value() {}
    HolderT(T const& t): _value(t) {}

    virtual HolderT* clone() const { return new HolderT(*this); }
    T _value;
};
```

And using this, a **true** compilation firewall:

```
template <typename T>
class pimpl {
public:
    /// Types
    typedef T value;
    typedef T const const_value;
    typedef T* pointer;
    typedef T const* const_pointer;
    typedef T& reference;
    typedef T const& const_reference;

    /// Gang of Five (and swap)
    pimpl(): _holder(new HolderT<T>()), _p(this->from_holder()) {}

    pimpl(const_reference t): _holder(new HolderT<T>(t)), _p(this->from_holder()) {}

    pimpl(pimpl const& other): _holder(other->_holder->clone()),
                               _p(this->from_holder())
    {}

    pimpl(pimpl&& other) = default;

    pimpl& operator=(pimpl t) { this->swap(t); return *this; }

    ~pimpl() = default;

    void swap(pimpl& other) {
        using std::swap;
        swap(_holder, other._holder);
        swap(_p, other._p)
    }

    /// Accessors
    pointer get() { return _p; }
    const_pointer get() const { return _p; }

    reference operator*() { return *_p; }
    const_reference operator*() const { return *_p; }

    pointer operator->() { return _p; }
    const_pointer operator->() const { return _p; }

private:
    T* from_holder() { return &static_cast< HolderT<T>& >(*_holder)._value; }

    std::unique_ptr<Holder> _holder;
    T* _p;           // local cache, not strictly necessary but avoids indirections
}; // class pimpl<T>

template <typename T>
void swap(pimpl<T>& left, pimpl<T>& right) { left.swap(right); }
```

Comment: I think your `pimpl` template is really neat - it never occurred to me to have a template for this so that I can easily have value semantics *and* hiding the private implementation without writing boilerplate code. I seem to recall that all code posted on StackOverflow is in the public domain - is this true for this code as well? I might want to use this in a commercial project I'm working on...

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: yes it is, feel free to use it, don't blame me if it blows up. (I would advise, with experience, replacing the `delete` with `boost::checked_delete`). Note that it *does not* really hide the implementation details (the definition of `T` must be visible). I have another (more complicated version) that reuses the principles of `shared_ptr` to capture a delete function as well.

Comment: Understood - however, what do you mean that the definition of `T` must be visible? `pimpl` holds merely a pointer, so a forward declaration should suffice. See http://ideone.com/rgFi0 for a tiny example demonstrating how I use your template (notice that the  `Private` struct is forward declared). It's really nice how the "big three" are not needed for `C`. :-)

Comment: Hm, maybe my code is exactly a case where `boost::checked_delete` would have triggered a compile error...

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: unfortunately, applying `delete` on a incomplete type (for example, forward declared) is undefined behavior. Most of the times it means that the destructor will not be called, too bad if it was not a POD. So the class, presented as is, is only an incomplete PIMPL. It preserves the ABI (the size is fixed), however it does not offer the compilation firewall guarantee (on its own). You still have to define the Big Three in a place where the full type is visible....

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: A variation consists in storing right alongside the pointer to `T` two function pointers: one to copy and one to delete. I'll edit the code to demonstrate.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: Added. It's in public domain, copylefted etc... and also completely untested (didn't even try to compile it, truth to be told). It reuses the same mechanism than `shared_ptr` does.

Comment: Patched a typo in `from_holder` (one cannot `static_cast` a `unique_ptr` directly...)

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with the same question.  Here's what I think the answer is:

You can do what you are suggesting, so long as you define the copy and assignment operators to do sensible things.

It's important to understand that the STL containers create copies of things.  So:

```
class Sample {
public:
    Sample() : m_Int(5) {}
    void Incr() { m_Int++; }
    void Print() { std::cout << m_Int << std::endl; }
private:
    int m_Int;
};

std::vector<Sample> v;
Sample c;
v.push_back(c);
c.Incr();
c.Print();
v[0].Print();
```

The output from this is:

```
6
5
```

That is, the vector has stored a copy of c, not c itself.

So, when you rewrite it as a PIMPL class, you get this:

```
class SampleImpl {
public:
    SampleImpl() : pimpl(new Impl()) {}
    void Incr() { pimpl->m_Int++; }
    void Print() { std::cout << m_Int << std::endl; }
private:
    struct Impl {
        int m_Int;
        Impl() : m_Int(5) {}
    };
    std::auto_ptr<Impl> pimpl;
};
```

Note I've mangled the PIMPL idiom a bit for brevity.  If you try to push this into a vector, it still tries to create a copy of the `SampleImpl` class.  But this doesn't work, because `std::vector` requires that the things it store provide a copy constructor that **doesn't modify the thing it's copying**.

An `auto_ptr` points to something that is owned by exactly one `auto_ptr`.  So when you create a copy of an `auto_ptr`, which one now owns the underlying pointer?  The old `auto_ptr` or the new one?  Which one is responsible for cleaning up the underlying object?  The answer is that ownership moves to the copy and the original is left as a pointer to `nullptr`.

What `auto_ptr` is missing that prevents its use in a vector is copy constructor taking a const reference to the thing being copied:

```
auto_ptr<T>(const auto_ptr<T>& other);
```

(Or something similar - can't remember all the template parameters).  If `auto_ptr` did provide this, and you tried to use the `SampleImpl` class above in the `main()` function from the first example, it would crash, because when you push `c` into the vector, the `auto_ptr` would transfer ownership of `pimpl` to the object in the vector and `c` would no longer own it.  So when you called `c.Incr()`, the process would crash with a segmentation fault on the `nullptr` dereference.

So you need to decide what the underlying semantics of your class are.  If you still want the 'copy everything' behaviour, then you need to provide a copy constructor that implements that correctly:

```
    SampleImpl(const SampleImpl& other) : pimpl(new Impl(*(other.pimpl))) {}
    SampleImpl& operator=(const SampleImpl& other) { pimpl.reset(new Impl(*(other.pimpl))); return *this; }
```

Now when you try to take a copy of a SampleImpl, you also get a copy of its Impl struct, owned by the copy SampleImpl.  If you're taking an object that had lots of private data members and was used in STL containers and turning it into a PIMPL class, then this is probably what you want, as it provides the same semantics as the original.  But note that pushing the object into a vector will be considerably slower as there is now dynamic memory allocation involved in copying the object.

If you decide you **don't** want this copy behaviour, then the alternative is for the copies of SampleImpl to share the underlying Impl object.  In this case, it's not longer clear (or even well-defined) which SampleImpl object owns the underlying Impl.  If ownership doesn't clearly belong in one place, then std::auto_ptr is the wrong choice for storing it 
and you need to use something else, probably a boost template.

**Edit**: I think the above copy constructor and assignment operator are exception-safe **so long as `~Impl` doesn't throw an exception**.  This should always be true of your code anyway.