# pimpl: Avoiding pointer to pointer with pimpl

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, pimpl-idiom, unique-ptr

In this question I asked ["pimpl: shared_ptr or unique_ptr"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576922/pimpl-shared-ptr-or-unique-ptr) I've been convinced that the proper usage of the pimpl idiom is to use a `unique_ptr`, not a `shared_ptr`. It should act to the user as if there is no pointer at all, whereas quite clearly the `shared_ptr` introduces aliasing upon copying, which definitely acts like a pointer.

So, lets say a user wants to create a `shared_ptr` to my pimpl object (say if they want actually want multiple aliases to it). For example:

```
shared_ptr<my_pimpl> p(new my_pimpl());
```

That would result in a `shared_ptr` pointing to a `unique_ptr` pointing to my implementation.

It would be nice if I could achieve something like the following:

```
my_pimpl x; // (1)
shared_ptr<my_pimpl> p(new my_pimpl()); // (2) Pointer to pointer here.
x.f(); // (3)
p->f(); // (4)
```

but with somehow getting rid of the pointer to pointer, whilst still maintaining the implementation hiding of pimpl.

Any ideas how to achieve this (I'm happy to change the line (2) and obviously `my_pimpl`, but want lines (3) and (4) to stay the same).

Comment: Is ’my_pimpl’ the public class or the private one?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't matter. If line 3 works, line 4 also works, assuming 'shared_ptr' has the expected semantics. Even if 'my_pimpl' is a typedef for 'unique_ptr<Impl>', 'operator->' will "drill down" into the underlying type just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of possible approaches depending on your constraints.

### 1. Create your own shared_my_pimpl class

Create a class `shared_my_pimpl` which has the same interface as `my_pimpl` but internally uses a shared_ptr instead of a `unique_ptr`. Now create a class `shared_ptr_my_pimpl` which holds a `shared_my_pimpl` and has an `operator->` which returns a pointer to the `shared_my_pimpl`, so that you get `->` notation instead of `.` notation for member access. You can add a function `make_shared_ptr_my_pimpl` to make it look more like `shared_ptr` usage.

Disadvantages:

1. The type of the object is not `shared_ptr<x>` but `shared_ptr_my_pimpl`; it's just pretending to be a `shared_ptr`.
2. You can't get a `my_pimpl*` or `my_pimpl&` to the object; it's a different type which just behaves the same.

### 2. Derive from an interface

Create an interface `my_pimpl_interface` with all relevant functions pure virtual. Derive both `my_pimpl` and `my_pimpl::impl` (your pimpl implementation class) from this interface. Add a function `make_shared_my_pimpl` which returns a `shared_ptr<my_pimpl_interface>` to a `my_pimpl::impl`. You can now refer to both the plain object and the shared_ptr object as `my_pimpl_interface&`.

Disadvantages:

1. By making all functions virtual you incur an extra indirection in calling them, which may have been what you were trying to avoid. Your standard `my_pimpl` object will also pay this overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an interface for this purpose, because then the user of your class can choose whether they want to use `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`.