# A non-shared smart pointer with incomplete types

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

Is there a standard pointer class (or Boost) which is a non-shared pointer that works with incomplete types?  I've gone over the C++11 standard and the boost library and can't find one, though it seems like a very useful type.

For example, I'd like to be able to make opaque types using a smart pointer.

```
  class A;
  wrap_ptr<A> some_func();
  void other_func( A const & );
```

`A` is an opaque type which can be used for a variety of functions. The user of the above interface has only an incomplete definition of A but should be able to delete/reset the pointer. I know the above can be done with a `shared_ptr` but that has an overhead I don't want in this particular code. `unique_ptr` has the right ownership semantics, but can't work with an incomplete type. In theory a wrapper should need only the overhead of having a pointer to a deleter.

Is there such a type in C++11 or the boost libraries?

*NOTE: I understand I can easily build this type, but I'd prefer a standard type if possible. It seems like it should be a fundamental smart pointer type.*

---

**UPDATE**: `unique_ptr` does not appear to be a good option. First off the syntax overhead would be offsetting. Secondly I'm not convinced it can be safely used with a custom deleter. I'll check to see how it might work.

Answer (score 10):

To be clear about unique_ptr : it does work with incomplete type, but if you use it in a header of a class like that :

```
#include <memory>

class A;

class B
{

std::unique_ptr<A> m_a;

};
```

It will not link because of the missing deleter implementation.
There is an easy fix to this : just define de destructor of the host class in a cpp, even if it's empty or should be the default one!

```
// B.hpp
#include <memory>

class A;

class B
{
public:

    B();
    ~B();

private:

std::unique_ptr<A> m_a;

};

// B.cpp

B::B(){} // or =default; (if you have a compiler providing it)
B::~B(){} // or =default; (if you have a compiler providing it)
```

Also, read answers to my question there : [Is std::unique_ptr<T> required to know the full definition of T?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012157/does-stdunique-ptrt-requires-to-know-the-full-t-definition)

And maybe take a look at how pimpl idiom (implying uncomplete type in a unique_ptr) is recommended to be implmented by Herb Sutter: http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_100/

Comment: This isn't the use I want. I want to use the pointer in the return value of the function, in a place where the caller will never see the complete type.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, `unique_ptr` can work with incomplete types, as long as you specify a custom deleter.

However, contrary to `shared_ptr`, this actually influence its type, as the custom deleter is precised statically (as the second template parameter).

Comment: While technically true, using this directly is syntactically unfriendly. You can't simply do `ptr_type( new T )` but, assuming you get the template typedef correct, you must do `ptr_type( new T, T::~T )`.

Comment: Actually, looking closely `unique_ptr` cannot use a custom deleter with a state. The `reset` function doesn't allow specifying a deleter, only the constructor does, therefore the custom deletion aspect of `unique_ptr` is partially broken.

Comment: No custom deleter needed, the type only needs to be complete when the destructor of `unique_ptr` would be invoked, which means you can define the destructor after the held class is complete.

Comment: @Xeo: First, The destructor is also necessary for move assignment and `reset` (I can't think of any other method). Secondly, the OP is not talking about a deferred definition, but about an Opaque Type. In C this is a typical case where the client never ever see the definition.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: "Actually, looking closely unique_ptr cannot use a custom deleter with a state." Not true. The standard specifically says that it will hold a copy of the deleter (20.7.1.2.1, p12). Just because `reset` can't reset the deleter's value doesn't mean the value is unused. `reset` doesn't take a deleter because deleters can be stored by reference in `unique_ptr`s. And thus you aren't guaranteed to be able to replace them.

Comment: @NicolBolas: this might still be taken as an oversight. After all, it is impossible to use move assignment if the deleter type is a reference, and still it exists. So one could have provided two overloads of `reset`, with and without resetting the deleter.

Comment: @MatthieuM. An oversight? Perhaps; they could use the same wording they use with move assignment. But an oversight is a far cry from saying you can't have deleters with state *at all*.

Answer (score 2):

`std::unique_ptr` can handle this case, but not with the default deleter. You need to write a deleter that can handle an incomplete type, and then use `std::unique_ptr<A,MyDeleter>`.