# Can't use parent class in nested class- even though nested class is defined afterwards

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

What I've got right now is a setup like this:

```
template<typename T> class Parent {
    struct Nested;
    std::unique_ptr<Nested> ptr;
public:
    // stuff
    ~Parent();
};
template<typename T> struct Parent<T>::Nested {
    Parent<T> p;
    // stuff
};
```

Visual Studio gives me an error that the `Nested` struct is using an incomplete type `Parent`- even though the definition is *after* the `Parent` class is complete.

How can I resolve this issue?

Edit: In case it wasn't apparent, I have used a delayed destructor definition until *after* the `Nested` class is defined to allow a `unique_ptr` to an incomplete type. In addition, it most definitely is not related to that, because the error isn't that `Nested` is incomplete- it's that `Nested` contains a member of type `Parent`, which is incomplete. In addition, if I explicitly erase the deleter by using `std::function<void(Nodes*)>` the problem is not solved.

Comment: This code compiles for me on MSVS2010 (after adding `#include <memory>` at the top)

Comment: **My bad** I have **incorrectly** vote to close as a exact duplicate, it is **not**. Don't vote to close.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is more with the `unique_ptr` and not with the class. Change it to shared_ptr or normal raw pointer and the code works fine.

Please find the below link from Stackoverflow.

[Does std::unique_ptr requires to know the full T definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012157/does-stdunique-ptrt-requires-to-know-the-full-t-definition)

**UPDATE**
As per the above link, the code works with `unique_ptr` if Parent was not templated.

Comment: `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` provide different types of functionality, if they could be randomly replaced with each other, they wouldn't exist as separate types would they?

Comment: Yes, I agree. But, this problem arises when you would want to use unique_ptr for a type that is does not have full definition yet.

Comment: :-) Just saying. It's ironical that the person who asked this question bagged 2 points for an answer I provided in the link. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6088400/124797

Comment: The first paragraph is wrong, the link provides a good answer to a related question (I bought it and vote to close as duplicate, it is not), and the update does not explain why the template should matter...

Comment: Except the technique of delaying the destructor is well-known and applied here. And secondly, if you look at the error, it's *not* that `Nested` is an incomplete type. It's that `Nested` contains a `Parent`, which is apparently incomplete.