# Forward declaration with unique_ptr

Tags: c++, destructor, forward-declaration, unique-ptr

I have found it useful to use forward declaration of classes in combination with `std::unique_ptr` as in the code below. It compiles and works with GCC, but the whole thing seem kind of strange, and I wonder if this is standard behaviour (i.e., required by the standard)? Since B isn't a complete type when I declare the `unique_ptr`.

#### A.hpp

```
#include <memory>

class B;

class A {
    std::unique_ptr<B> myptr;
    // B::~B() can't be seen from here
public:
    ~A();
};
```

#### A.cpp

```
#include "B.hpp"
//B.hpp has to be included, otherwise it doesn't work.

A::~A() = default; // without this line, it won't compile
// however, any destructor definition will do.
```

I suspect this has to do with the destructor (and therefore the need to call the destructor of `unique_ptr<B>`) is defined in a specific compilation unit (A.cpp).

Answer (score 107, accepted):

It's explicitly legal.  The rule is that the types used to instantiate
a template in the standard library must be complete, *unless* otherwise
specified.  In the case of `unique_ptr`, §20.7.1/5 says “[...] The
template parameter T of unique_ptr may be an incomplete type.”

There are certain operations on the pointer which require a complete
type; in particular, when the object will actually be destructed (at
least with the default deleter).  In your example, for example, if
`A::~A()` were inline, this might cause problems.  (Note that if you
don't declare the destructor yourself, it will be inline.  Which
partially defeats the purpose of using `std::unique_ptr`.)

Comment: "Which partially defeats the purpose of using std::unique_ptr" What do you mean? Doesn't a class instance automatically delete its members if you don't declare the dtor?

Comment: So, it isn't possible to create a custom template class with similar functionality to `unique_ptr` as the C++ standard defines custom rules for `unique_ptr` to let if work?

Comment: Wow, it was the destructor causing the issues. As soon as I explicitly defined it in my .cpp file everything went away.

Comment: How would this be fixed if A.hpp was an abstract class?