# C++11 container of unique_ptr of forward declared class

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr, forward-declaration

`g++ -std=c++11` does not compile a class that contains a container that contains unique pointers that point to a forward declared class. Questions:

- Why?
- Is there a reasonable workaround?

Code example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

// variant 1 (with full class definition): compiles
class Bar { [..] }; 
using BarPtr = std::unique_ptr<Bar>;

// variant 2 (with shared instead of unique pointers): compiles
using BarPtr = std::shared_ptr<class Bar>;

// variant 0 (which is what we want): compilation fails below
using BarPtr = std::unique_ptr<class Bar>;

// end of variants

class Foo {
    std::vector<BarPtr> vec;
 public:
    Foo() {} // compilation of variant 0 fails here:
             // In instantiation of ‘void std::default_delete<Bar>::operator()(Bar*) const
             // ... 
             // invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘Bar’
};
```

I have seen [How to forward declare a class to be used in a standard container of unique_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25795363/how-to-forward-declare-a-class-to-be-used-in-a-standard-container-of-unique-ptr) and [Is std::unique_ptr<T> required to know the full definition of T?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012157/is-stdunique-ptrt-required-to-know-the-full-definition-of-t), but do not find convincing answers to my above questions.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move those parts of Foo to the implementation file, that need to full definition of Bar (see table by Howard Hinnant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6089065/2173029). Following this guideline, this compiles:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Bar;
using BarPtr = std::unique_ptr<Bar>;

class Foo {
    std::vector<BarPtr> vec;
 public:
    Foo(); // Needs Bar in implementation
    ~Foo();// Needs Bar in implementation
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Bar;
using BarPtr = std::unique_ptr<Bar>;

class Foo {
    std::vector<BarPtr> vec;
 public:
    Foo() {} // variant 3 fails here:
             // invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘Bar’
};


//Implementation goes here
class Bar{};
int main(){
    Foo a;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://cpp.sh/9ffx)

Comment: I confirm that this compiles under g++. The `main` program is not needed. However, the implementation `class Bar { [...] };` is. So the order in the source file does not matter. However, I want to implement class `Bar` in another compilation unit.

Comment: Yes main is just to make sure that everything is fine. When you want to a forward declaration you need to finally implement the class somewhere to not get linking problem or maybe in your case compile-error due to the absence of deleter (deconstructor)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot delete by pointer to incomplete (forward declared) type. Make sure the definition of `Bar` is visible in the destructor of the containing class, or use a custom deleter for the `unique_ptr` that sees it. See also [std::unique_ptr with an incomplete type won't compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954518/stdunique-ptr-with-an-incomplete-type-wont-compile)

Comment: The compilation fails in the *constructor* `Foo()`; adding a destructor `~Foo()` doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

The error message at line

```
Foo() {};
```

seems to tell that a destructor `~Bar()` is required. But why? This part of my question is still open.

As for the practical solution, however, the answer is simple: Replace the above line by

```
Foo();
```

and implement `Foo::Foo` in a compilation unit that sees the full definition of class `Bar`.

Comment: how this differ from my answer?

Comment: and be aware that if you did not implement a constructor, a default one will be implemented automatically.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, *declaration* of a constructor will prevent automatic *implementation* of a default.

Comment: This doesn't really explain the problem. The presence of a constructor implementation is not a problem. The problem is actually the absence of the `~Bar()` function (not anything to do with the Foo destructor either).  Read the full error messages to see why - you disingenuously only pasted one line of the errors in the question.

Comment: I agree that the *Why* in my question is not yet answered. I edited the question and my partial answer.

Comment: @JoachimWuttke Regarding the *why*, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012157/is-stdunique-ptrt-required-to-know-the-full-definition-of-t