# "Use of undefined type" with unique_ptr to forward declared class and defaulted move constructor/assignment

Tags: c++, c++11

In the following code, is the only way to avoid a compile error and to include B.h implementing the move constructor / assignment manually in A.cpp?

```
// A.h
#include <memory>
class B; // implementation somewhere in B.h/B.cpp
class A
{
public:
    A() = default;
    ~A() = default;
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A& operator=(const A&) = delete;
    A(A&&) = default;
    A& operator=(A&&) = default;

private:
    std::unique_ptr<B> m_b;
};
```

Visual Studio 2015 gives "error C2027: use of undefined type", since the move constructor/assignment operator of std::unique_ptr calls the deleter on m_b (trying to invoke B's destructor), which is obviously not known at this point.

Comment: related/dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13414652/forward-declaration-with-unique-ptr

Comment: I actually didn't know that you could = default in .cpp, too. I thought it was required on declaration. So the proper way of handling my specific case would simply be to declare the move constructor as A(A&&) noexcept; in A.h and define it as A::A(A&&)  noexcept = default; in A.cpp. Thanks!

Comment: That sounds like a good idea.

Comment: This is a better solution than the accepted answer imo.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, you need to have access to the full definition of `B` from wherever you instantiate `std::unique_ptr<B>::~unique_ptr`, because it needs to call `B`'s destructor.

In your case, that means that `A::~A`'s definition must be moved to a separate `A.cpp` file, which includes `B.h`.

Comment: To be clear, `~A() = default;` can be moved into the cpp file as `A::~A() = default;` - there's no need to implement it manually. Same for any other methods with this issue.