# Can't push_back an unique_ptr in a vector

Tags: c++, vector, game-engine, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I am having an error with this code:

```
void Game::changeState(gameState type) // gameState is an enum
{
   if (!states.empty()) // deleting the last state
   {
       states.back()->clean();
       states.pop_back();
   }

   switch(type)
   {
       case editorState:
       {
           states.push_back(std::move(std::unique_ptr<EditorState> (new EditorState)));
           states.back()->init();
           break;
       }
       case menuState:
       {
           states.push_back(std::move(std::unique_ptr<MenuState> (new MenuState)));
           states.back()->init();
           break;
       }

   }
}
```

The vector :

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<GameState>> states;
```

The error message:

> c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\bits\unique_ptr.h||**In instantiation of 'void std::default_delete<_Tp>::operator()(_Tp*) const [with _Tp = GameState]':|**
>   c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\bits\unique_ptr.h|245|**required from 'void std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::reset(std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::pointer) [with _Tp = GameState; _Dp = std::default_delete; std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::pointer = GameState*]'|** 
>   c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\bits\unique_ptr.h|169|**required from 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::~unique_ptr() [with _Tp = GameState; _Dp = std::default_delete]'|**
>   c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\bits\stl_construct.h|95|**required from 'void std::_Destroy(_Tp*) [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr]'|**
>   c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\bits\stl_construct.h|105|**required from 'static void std::_Destroy_aux< >::__destroy(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _ForwardIterator = std::unique_ptr*; bool  = false]'|**
>   c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\bits\stl_construct.h|128|**required from 'void std::_Destroy(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _ForwardIterator = std::unique_ptr*]'|**
>   c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\bits\stl_construct.h|155|**required from 'void std::_Destroy(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_T2>&) [with _ForwardIterator = std::unique_ptr*; _Tp = std::unique_ptr]'|**
>   c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\bits\stl_vector.h|403|**required from 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::~vector() [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr; _Alloc = std::allocator >]'|**
>   ...\game.h|15|**required from here|**
>   c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\bits\unique_ptr.h|63|**error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'GameState'|**
>   ||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 12 warnings (0 minutes, 1 seconds) ===|

My code above works when i use default pointers, but when i am using unique_ptr it gives me the error above ...

**EDIT:** Here is the game.h : http://pastebin.com/DiBbXrC6
And gamestate : http://pastebin.com/JD3VrktJ

Comment: First of all, `unique_ptr` will be moved by default, so no need for `std::move`. Secondly, try `states.emplace_back(new EditorState);` instead.

Comment: The important part about it is *"error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'GameState'"* so please show us the context. It seems that the definition of this function `Game::changeState` does not see the dtor of `GameState`.

Comment: @Joachim emplace_back doesn't work too.

Comment: @dyp i'm sending the code in a few minutes ...

Comment: The most interesting part is inside `game.h` - the code above looks irrelevant to the error.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: is that exception-safe?

Comment: i've edited my message, now you have the code

Comment: Then, my answer is correct - I can expand it, if you need more explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `unique_ptr` you need to explicitly define the class `T` where-ever you declare the `unique_ptr<T>`. I.e. include the header for the `class GameState`, do not forward declare in the header `game.h`.

This will get rid of `error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'GameState'`.

You can find more detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6089065/377393).

Comment: Well I think this is the problem, thanks, i'll try something else for changing my states