# How works - Pointer / Unique_ptr without new

Tags: c++, pointers, undefined-behavior, unique-ptr

**foo.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Bar
{
public:
    Bar() {};
    ~Bar() {};
    void print() {
        std::cout << "hello";
    }
};

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(); 
    ~Foo();
    void use() {
        pteste->print();
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Bar> pteste;
};

#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <memory>
#include "foo.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    Foo s;
    s.use();

    return 0;
}
```

Why and how does it works "normally"?

Thanks

EDIT: I understand about the incomplete types, but what happens when I can use unique_ptr without using new and why works

EDIT2: Organized the code better for my question

Comment: To start with, you should mark the destructor as `default` in the class definition.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` is much like any other pointer, it doesn't need the complete definition when defining a variable, it just needs to know that the type exists.

Comment: @Joachim foo.cpp already has default destructor

Comment: What I mean is that no one else using the `Foo` class will know that the destructor has been marked with `default`. It's only known in the `foo.cpp` translation unit.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg That would break things, no? If you do that, the unique_ptr would not be able to find the `Bar` destructor. The only way for this to work is for the destructor *not* to be defined in the class definition.

Comment: This is a very good related post: [Is std::unique_ptr<T> required to know the full definition of T?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012157/is-stdunique-ptrt-required-to-know-the-full-definition-of-t).

Comment: @juanchopanza Are we still talking about the `default` of the **`Foo`** destructor? I fail how that will break the `Bar` destructor?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg why I need make the foo default destructor available? I only make it default, so I dont need include bar.h in the header of foo.h

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Sorry, my bad. I meant the `Foo` destructor. See the link above.

Comment: @Tietbohl What I mean is that in `foo.cpp` you tell the compiler to use the default destructor for the class `Foo`. But that only tells the compiler to do it in the `foo.cpp` file. In `main.cpp` the compiler doesn't know that the `Foo` destructor is supposed to be the default destructor. It might cause the compiler to generate unoptimal code.

Comment: @juanchopanza good link, maybe my question is more "what happens in undefined behavior" and I only catch one particular case in my question

Comment: @JoachimPileborg how can I avoid includes on the header (thats why i use default constructor in implementation) or help to generate more optimal code

Comment: Your second edit makes the current answers pretty much useless. The current code always has the full definition of `Bar` now.

Comment: @Tietbohl In `main.cpp`, if the compiler knows that the destructor is the default destructor, it can easily inline the destructor. Now when compiling `main.cpp` the compiler thinks that you have a custom destructor, and will call that "custom" (but really default) destructor.

Comment: @Excelcius my question is about why it works, and how, even if I dont declare new. I think I formulated it wrong at the first time

Comment: @Tietbohl That's ok, but the question title and the text below the code still says there are issues with incomplete types. This is no longer the case. Please edit your question so the text and title match the current code.

Comment: @Excelcius yeah, maybe some moderator could deleted this question, I'll think more carefully next time, thanks

Comment: @Tietbohl It doesn't have to be deleted, it looks better now and it focuses on one question instead of two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: It doesn't work.

This [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) says that the default constructor of `std::unique_ptr` creates an empty unique pointer, meaning it has no associated object.

The reason why this code prints `hello` is because this statement

```
std::cout << "hello";
```

doesn't need anything of `Bar`. It could just as well be a static method. Maybe the compiler inlines the function and replaces `s.use()` with the `std::cout`-statement. But even if it does call the method, you won't notice any errors since it doesn't access the memory of `Bar` at all.

Make a slight change to your class and you will see what I mean:

```
class Bar
{
public:
    Bar() : data(10) {};
    ~Bar() {};
    void print() {
        std::cout << "hello, data is: " << data;
    }

    int data;
};
```

Now, `print` accesses invalid memory, because you never called `new` (or even better: `make_unique`). It may even work and print something to the console, but the output of `data` will be garbage. If you're lucky, the application will crash.

Another reason why it appears to work (thanks Stas):

`std::unique_ptr` defines `operator->`, which simply returns the contained pointer, but does not check if the pointer points to valid memory. So `pteste->` won't throw an exception.

Comment: Yes, good explanation. May be it makes sense to note that `operator->()` of `unique_ptr<T>` does nothing and just return T* as you decided to not simplify it to naked pointer )

Comment: @Stas I added it to the answer.

Comment: thanks for the complete answer, I get segmentation fault trying to access data, and using only a pointer the compiler warns me about uninitialized pointer (thanks @Stas)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this code will "normally" print "hello" to console and it is not related to `unique_ptr`. You can replace `std::unique_ptr<Bar> pteste` with `Bar* pteste` in `Bar` and get the same result.

Consider how `pteste->print()` is called.

You can think about `Bar::print()` as a free function that take pointer to `Bar` object:

```
void print(Bar* this) {
    std::cout << "hello";
}
```

See, pointer passed to `print(Bar*)` is never touched, so you can theoretically pass whatever you want (null, garbage etc.) and it will print "hello" to console.

Comment: thanks by pointer/unique_ptr and for the implicity this, didnt know.

Answer (score 0):

It works because

```
std::unique_ptr<Bar> pteste;
```

is a pointer declaration to the instance, it does not instantiate the pointer so it does not need to know at this point the details about Bar (e.g. ctor).

In the case of

```
Bar pteste
```

in order for pteste to be constructed it will need the know definition but since Bar is only forward declared it will give an error.

Answer (score 0):

All pointers are implemented the same way. Even though you have pointers to different types, all are the size of an int usually. So the compiler does not need to know about the type of the pointee when it compiles your code. Now if you were to dereference that pointer that would be a different story. Even if you would initialize your `unique_ptr` it would need to know the type, since `new` needs to see the constructor.

Comment: thanks, yes, I notice about the constructor and destructor right now, this is because the undefined behavior I caused (I believe this is all about I wanted to know)?

Comment: I must admit I didn't know it was undefined behaviour. Although I have had trouble with code like yours. Cool to know it :)