# Avoid cyclic dependencies - need for mutual containment

Tags: c++, containment, mutual-recursion

In my GUI system, the main building block is `Container` class, which **can be drawn** (= is drawable). However, `Container` itself is a '*kind of a table*' - it contains cells.

`Cell` class serves for **layouting**. The number of cells a container has is defined by number of rows and columns.`Cell` objects are not visible.

And here's the problem. `Cell` objects cannot be drawn - they contain `Container` objects, which are drawn by the rules defined in the `Cell` object (alignment, padding, etc..) when calling `cell.draw()`.

I know this can be easily resolved by using raw pointers to avoid the circular dependency created here, but I wanted to use smart pointers, if possible. However, according to error I'm getting, it's obvious smart pointers **have to know** the size of the object, unlike raw pointers.

**Unique_ptr error**

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:65:22: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘Container’
  static_assert(sizeof(_Tp)>0,
```

**Container.hpp**

```
#include <Cell.hpp> // Causes circular dependency
class Cell; // Causes error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’

class Container
{
// ...
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Cell>> cells;
// ...
}
```

**Cell.hpp**

```
#include <Container.hpp> //Causes circular dependency
class Container; // Causes error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’
class Cell
{
// ...
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_prt<Container>> subcontainers;
// ...
}
```

Is there a nice way how to solve the situation using smart pointers (maybe by redesigning the whole problem solution), or do I have to use raw pointers here?

Comment: I don't really see why you would *have* this kind of cycle. What is the *sense* of a Container containing Cells containing Containers? Even if you get it done on a *syntactic* level, it seems like poor design *semantically*...

Comment: Have you considered using references instead of pointers?

Comment: I think you should have one container, containing containers :D each container has a getCells() method

Comment: What would you recommend?

@DevSolar: The basic idea was to have a drawable object, which could be easily divided in parts, where each part could have more drawable objects.
For example, Window itself would be a container, the header would be a container, the body would be as well..

Comment: Drop the circular include and ensure the destructor of the unique_ptr is invoked in a source file (where you include all headers, needed). In other words, you cannot define the destructor in the header.

Comment: okay it's an answer now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::unique_ptr` works on forward declared types, but it needs to know the full type for invoking the deleter.

This will bite you if your class uses a compiler-generated destructor. You can get rid of the problem by defining a (possibly empty) custom destructor for the class out-of-line in a source file where the full type definition for the type held by the `unique_ptr` is visible.

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6089065/577603) for the gory details.

Comment: I have defined destructor (and even copy constructor and assignment operator) in implementation file. The problem is, however, still there. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Dundee Not without a more details. Could you post the full error message that you get from the compiler, including all steps of the template instantiation stack?

Comment: The problem was a namespace-problem. I forgot to put the forward-declaration in the appropriate namespace. Thank you for your help. Apologies for my idiocy.

Answer (score 0):

The answer:
I think you should have one container, containing containers :D each container has a getCells() method.

Comment: But save them as smart pointers (shared or unique). You don't want to be copied all the time I think?