# Why does unique_ptr<T>::~unique_ptr need the definition of T?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, smart-pointers

If I have a class 'Bar':

```
// bar.h
class Bar
{
public:

    Bar() { }
};
```

that I forward declare to use with an std::unique_ptr in another class 'Foo':

```
// foo.h
#include <memory>

class Bar;

class Foo
{

public:

    Foo();

private:

    std::unique_ptr<Bar> bar_;
};
```

and whose definition I include in the implementation file of Foo:

```
// foo.cpp
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"

Foo::Foo()
: bar_(new Bar)
{ }
```

I get the the compile-time error "Invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type 'Bar'".

I understand from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012157/is-stdunique-ptrt-required-to-know-the-full-definition-of-t) and [here](http://www.codesynthesis.com/~boris/blog/2012/04/04/when-provide-empty-destructor/) that to fix this, I can declare Foo's destructor in foo.h and move its empty definition to foo.cpp. What I don't understand is, why that fixes it. I read that std::unique_ptr sometimes requires to know the full definition of its type. It would make sense to me if I would have to include Bar from bar.h so that the unique_ptr sees its definition. But what does the destructor of Foo have to do with the visibility of Bar, and why does declaring ~Foo() in foo.h and defining it in foo.cpp silence the error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The destructor of `unique_ptr<Bar>` calls `Bar::~Bar` when it `delete`'s the `Bar` it owns.  So `~unique_ptr<Bar>` needs to see `Bar::~Bar`.

But template methods are only instantiated at point of use.

The unique ptr is destroyed by the `Foo` in `Foo::~Foo`.  If `~Foo` lives where it can see the definition of `~Bar`, all is good.

If you leave it to be generated by the compiler, it 'lives' in the declaration of `Foo`, where it cannot see `~Bar`.

If you forward declare it, then do a `Foo::~Foo() = default` or `Foo::~Foo() {}` in the `.cpp` file after `#include <bar.h>`, it can see `~Bar` at the point where `~std::unique_ptr<Bar>` is called`, and all is good.

This matters in practice because how `Bar` is destroyed differs depending on if `~Bar` is virtual, and if `Bar` has parents, and if `~Bar` is private/protected it might be illegal to call.

Comment: "If you leave it to be generated by the compiler, it 'lives' in the declaration of Foo, where it cannot see ~Bar". Is this because the compiler-generated destructor is automatically inlined?

Comment: @vsoftco where else could it go?  No translation unit has precidence.