# Requirements on returned type that may have some member functions SFINAE'd away in the function's translation unit?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Refining from [Why is the destructor implicitly called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71784284/why-is-the-destructor-implicitly-called)

My understanding of calling convention is that functions construct their result where the caller asked them to (or in a conventional place?). With that in mind, this surprises me:

```
#include <memory>

struct X; // Incomplete type.

// Placement-new a null unique_ptr in-place:
void constructAt(std::unique_ptr<X>* ptr) { new (&ptr) std::unique_ptr<X>{nullptr}; }

// Return a null unique_ptr:
std::unique_ptr<X> foo() { return std::unique_ptr<X>{nullptr}; }
```

https://godbolt.org/z/rqb1fKq3x
Whereas `constructAt` compiles, happily placement-`new`ing a null `unique_ptr<X>`, `foo()` doesn't compile because the compiler wants to instantiate `unique_ptr<X>::~unique_ptr()`. I understand why it can't instantiate that destructor (because as far as the language is concerned, it needs to follow the non-`nullptr` branch of the d'tor that then deletes the memory [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28521950/why-does-unique-ptrtunique-ptr-need-the-definition-of-t]). Basically without a complete `X`, the `unique_ptr`'s destructor is SFINAE'd away (right?). But why does a function returning a value have to know how to destruct that value? Isn't the caller the one that will have to destruct it?

Clearly my `constructAt` and `foo` functions aren't morally equivalent. Is this language pedantry, or is there some code path (exceptions?) where `foo()` would have to destruct that value?

Comment: So, you don't call `delete` on your pointer to `std::unique_ptr` (which does not trigger destructor's invocation) and then conclude that its destructor was "SFINAEd away"? Just call `delete ptr` in your first example and you will see the same error as in `foo` case

Comment: "*is there some code path (exceptions?) where foo() would have to destruct that value*" -  it returns a *temporary* object which will be *inevitably* destroyed some time after `foo()` invocation. The compiler *does not* know from the function's definition itself whether you will or not move the pointer's object. It requires `X` to be complete by the time of destruction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your specific case there is no way that the destructor may be invoked. However, the standard specifies the situations in which the destructor is *potentially invoked* in more general terms. If a destructor is *potentially invoked* it requires a definition (even if there is no path that could call it) and this will therefore cause implicit instantiation which fails in your case since instantiation of the `std::unique_ptr<X>` destructor requires `X` to be complete.

In particular the destructor is *potentially invoked* for every result object in a `return` statement.

I think the reason for this choice is described in [CWG issue 2176](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#2176): In general there may be local variables and temporaries in the function which are destroyed after the result object of the `return` statement has been constructed. But if the destruction of one of these objects throws an exception, then the already constructed result object should also be destroyed. This requires the destructor to be defined.

[CWG issue 2426](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#2426) then made the destructor potentially invoked even if there is no actual invocation due to the above reasoning, in line with implementations. I assume this choice was made simply because it doesn't require any additional decision making on the compiler's part and was already implemented.

Comment: The wording from CWG2176 doesn't actually apply since there are no local variables or temporaries. [CWG2426](http://wg21.link/cwg2426) is the one that makes the destructor always potentially-invoked to match with what implementations actually did (always instantiate the destructor).

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense (although it's annoying, that the standard hasn't streamlined the common case that no locals have throwing destructors). But I think I understand http://wg21.link/cwg2426.

Is that the only reason this doesn't work? I had thought RVO would have meant that in the absence of exceptions it would always be the caller's job to destruct the returned result. It sounds like my understanding is correct except for this CWG forcing the d'tor to be "potentially invoked".

Comment: @Ben Actually, after thinking about it for a moment, I think it wouldn't be too hard to give useful limitations on this. Throwing destructors are not common anyway, so something like "the destructor is potentially invoked if the function definition contains any parameters, local variables or temporary objects of class type with potentially throwing destructor" might work. But I am not sure whether I am overlooking some problem with that approach or whether it was just not deemed worth it to complicate the resolution of the issue.

Comment: OK, so I've found a sufficiently interesting/subtle case that the answer is "write a paper to fix it!" :-D