# How to assign a unique_ptr with a custom deleter

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, unique-ptr, allegro

I am trying to pass a pointer to a function that then sets a `unique_ptr` inside a struct to the pointer passed in. However, I get the following compile error on the last line of the function.

> error C2280: 'std::unique_ptr< ALLEGRO_BITMAP,std::default_delete< ALLEGRO_BITMAP>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr< ALLEGRO_BITMAP,std::default_delete< ALLEGRO_BITMAP>> &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function
>
> c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\memory(1486) : see declaration of 'std::unique_ptr< ALLEGRO_BITMAP,std::default_delete< ALLEGRO_BITMAP>>::unique_ptr'
>
> This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'Skin::Skin(const Skin &)'

Judging from the errors I believe it has something to do with me adding the delete template for `ALLEGRO_BITMAP` to namespace std, but I don't know why or how to fix it.

```
using namespace std;

namespace std {
template<>
class default_delete < ALLEGRO_BITMAP > {
public:
    void operator()(ALLEGRO_BITMAP* ptr) {
        al_destroy_bitmap(ptr);
    }
};
}

typedef struct {
    unique_ptr<ALLEGRO_BITMAP> img;
} Skin;

typedef struct {
    Skin skins[MAX_ENTITY_COUNT];
} World;

unsigned int createBlock(World world, ALLEGRO_BITMAP* img) {
    unsigned int entity = newEntityIndex(world);
    world.skins[entity].img = make_unique<ALLEGRO_BITMAP>(img);
    return entity;
} // error on this line
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: 1) The example given is not self-contained. 2) unique_ptr has certain requirements (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6089065/2549876).

Comment: You should not be using `make_unique` here. ALLEGRO_BITMAP should only be used through an [opaque pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer). You should not directly create ALLEGRO_BITMAP objects, which is what `make_unique` will do. You should just use the `unique_ptr` constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `createBlock` function you take `World` by value which means that it will be copied. However, you can't copy a `unique_ptr` so that is where your error comes from. This would also mean that setting the `unqiue_ptr` in the function wouldn't have any effect.

Instead you should take World by reference:

```
unsigned int createBlock(World& world, ALLEGRO_BITMAP* img) {
    unsigned int entity = newEntityIndex(world);
    world.skins[entity].img = make_unique<ALLEGRO_BITMAP>(img);
    return entity;
}
```

Note that the same is true for the call to `newEntityIndex` and that the arguments to `make_unique` will be passed to the `ALLEGRO_BITMAP` constructor.

So what you probably want is:

```
world.skins[entity].img.reset(img);
```