# How to use unique_ptr with forward declared type?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

It is quite common to have forward declarations in order to avoid cyclic header file dependencies, or to implement pimpl, then one might end up with code like:

```
class A;

class B
{
  A * a;
};
```

When one tries to replace this with a unique_ptr:

```
class A;

class B
{
  std::unique_ptr<A> a;
};
```

the compiler complains. What is the best practice to get this working?

Comment: Did you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012157/is-stdunique-ptrt-required-to-know-the-full-definition-of-t ?

Comment: Ensure `A` is defined (not just forward declared) before declaring a `std::unique_ptr<A>`.   By default, `unique_ptr` uses operator `delete` (or a variant) to release the object, and that requires using either a basic non-class type (`int`, enums, unions, etc) or invoking the destructor of a `struct`/`class` type (which will not be declared with only a forward declaration of the class).

Comment: Just define everything that needs to know the complete type when it is known. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/92407ffd3e333a97

Comment: @m.s. well that question is a bit convoluted. I am looking for something straightforward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One needs to declare the destructor of the enclosing class B, and set this to default in the source file, such that the unique_ptr does not forcibly inline its own default deleter.

```
class B
{
  public:
  ~B();
  private:
  std::unique_ptr<A> a;
};
```

and in the source file

```
#include <A.h>
... do stuff with ( a )
B::~B() = default;
```

Should do the job.