# Circular dependency: can't delete an incomplete type

Tags: c++, oop, smart-pointers

I don't understand why I get this compiler errors:

> ```
> error C2027: use of undefined type 'GameState'
> note: see declaration of 'GameState'
> error C2338: can't delete an incomplete type warning C4150: deletion of pointer to incomplete type 'GameState'; no destructor called
> ```

This is the relevant code:

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include "SpawnManager.h"
#include "Resource.h"
#include <stack>
#include <memory>
class GameState;

class Controller
{
public:
    Controller();
    void run();
    void setPlayerScore(unsigned score);
    sf::RenderWindow& getWindow() { return m_window; }
    void addState(const States& state);
    void changeState(const States& state);
    GameState* getState() const;
    void popState();
    void add_state(const States& type, Controller * cont);
    ~Controller() {}

private:
    SpawnManager<States, GameState> m_sFactory;
    sf::RenderWindow m_window;
    ScoreRecord m_playerScore;
    std::stack<std::unique_ptr<GameState>> m_screens;
};

#pragma once
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include "Controller.h"

//State design pattern
class GameState
{
public:
    explicit GameState(Controller* state_holder);
    GameState(const GameState&) = delete;
    GameState(GameState&&) = delete;
    GameState& operator=(const GameState&) = delete;
    GameState& operator=(GameState&&) = delete;
    virtual ~GameState() = default;

    virtual void displayState() = 0;
    virtual void updateStage() = 0;
    virtual void handleEvent(sf::Event& event) = 0;

protected:
    std::unique_ptr<Controller> m_state;
};
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012157/is-stdunique-ptrt-required-to-know-the-full-definition-of-t Try to move the implementation of `~Controller()` to an implementation file where `GameState` is a complete type.

Comment: I don't think it's good design to have 2 classes depend on each other like that. You might want to rethink your design.

Comment: template <typename T1, typename T2>
SpawnManager<States, GameState>::SpawnManager() @Bathsheba

Comment: its State design pattern @Rakete1111

Comment: @TalorT But they can't both own each other, as they do in your case. The first deleted `GameState` will delete the controller.

Comment: Two objects point to each other with a unique_ptr? What would that mean?

Comment: @Angew technically, it could be a sort of linked list structure where every other object is a `Controller` with `GameState` objects in between. That list may not loop to itself of course. But it wouldn't be far fetched to assume that's not what OP was going for.

Comment: @TalorT ...but you combine it with a circular dependency anti-pattern.

Answer (score 12):

The definition of the destructor of `std::unique_ptr<T>` requires `T` to be complete i.e. defined, not just declared. Since a `std::unique_ptr<GameState>` is a(n indirect) member of `Controller`, the definition of destructor `~Controller` requires the definition of the destructor of `std::unique_ptr<GameState>` and therefore also the definition of `GameState`, which was not provided.

Solution: Define `GameState` before you define `~Controller`. A minimal example:

```
struct GameState;

// 1. Definition of Controller
struct Controller
{
    ~Controller();
    std::stack<std::unique_ptr<GameState>> m_screens;
};

// 2. Definition of GameState
struct GameState
{
    std::unique_ptr<Controller> m_state;
};

// 3. Definition of Controller::~Controller
Controller::~Controller(){} // or = default;
```

---

P.S. Consider that you can never have a `GameState` be pointed by a `Controller` that points to that same `GameState`. In such situation you would end up with an infinite recursion of destructions of already destructed objects. And multiple `GameStates` can not own the same `Controller` and vice versa. Consider whether your ownership structure makes sense. I suspect that you need either shared ownership, or non-owning referral.

Comment: You might also want to comment on the weird mutual ownership which seems to be present in OP's code.

Comment: @Angew I added a mention, although it's slightly off topic from the question itself.