# Forward Declarations and std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, forward-declaration

I am having trouble making forward declarations work with std::unique_ptr.  I have read other similar posts on SO and elsewhere online, but either the answers in those posts do not directly address my concern, or I am misinterpreting/misunderstanding the answers.  So, in case someone feels that this is a duplicate question (esp. with reference to [Is std::unique_ptr<T> required to know the full definition of T?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012157/is-stdunique-ptrt-required-to-know-the-full-definition-of-t)), please clarify how the answers in the original question help my example below, because I tried and could not figure it out.

To illustrate the issues I am running into, I have built a project with the following code files:

```
//main.cpp
int main(int argv, char* argv[]) { return 0;}

//Composite.h
#pragma once
#include<memory>

class Individual;

class Composite
{
public:
    Composite();
    ~Composite();
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Individual> mInd;
};

//Composite.cpp
#include "Composite.h"

Composite::Composite() {}
Composite::~Composite() {}

//Individual.h
#pragma once
class Individual
{
public:
    Individual();
    ~Individual();
};

//Individual.cpp
#include "Individual.h"

Individual::Individual() {}
Individual::~Individual() {}
```

I am unable to compile the above project in Visual Studio 2017.  Essentially the compiler complains of:

> Error C2027: use of undefined type "Individual"
>
> Error C2338: can't delete an incomplete type

Note that neither `Composite` nor `Individual` is instantiated, which is on purpose to illustrate the problem.  Whatever I found on SO and elsewhere online seems to suggest the above files should compile because:

1. The compiler needs to know the complete definition of `Individual` before `Composite` is instantiated.  Since `Composite` is never instantiated, there should be no compilation errors.
2. A number of solutions online suggest that defining an empty destructor in the .cpp file (instead of defining it in the header file) should resolve issues related to std::unique_ptr and incomplete types.  I have done that in the above files.

So, why the compilation errors?

P.S. I have read the post at [Is std::unique_ptr<T> required to know the full definition of T?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012157/is-stdunique-ptrt-required-to-know-the-full-definition-of-t). There is a table provided in the accepted answer that I cannot make any sense of.  The constructor/destructor requirements in that table... does it apply to the owning class or the class for which the std::unique_ptr is constructed?  In fact, the third comment to the answer essentially advises to provide some clarification, but the comment was not responded to as far as I can tell.

Thanks in advance to all those who bothered to help.

Comment: add `#include "Individual.h"` at the top of Composite.cpp

Comment: When `Composite::~Composite() {}` is compiled, it calls the destructor of `unique_ptr` which is supposed to delete the `Individual` pointed to. But it cannot as it doesn't know *anything* about `Individual`'s destructor. Not even if there is one. You could have `~Individual() = delete;`.

Comment: Thanks @axalo for the fix!

Comment: Thanks @BoPersson for the explanation!