# Use unique_ptr<T> with forward declearation leads to C2027 and C2338

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

Here is a simple version of code:

```
//Outer.h
class Inner;

class Outer
{
    std::unique_ptr<Inner> m_ptr;
public:
    ~Outer();
}

//----------------------------------------
//Outer.cpp
#include "Outer.h"
#include "Inner.h"  //here is the full definition of class Inner

Outer::~Outer(){};

//----------------------------------------
//main.cpp
#include "Outer.h"

int main()
{
    Outer b;
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile "main.cpp", the compiler returns with C2338(can't delete an incomplete type) and C2027(use of undefined type 'Inner')

I have read [Is std::unique_ptr required to know the full definition of T?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012157/is-stdunique-ptrt-required-to-know-the-full-definition-of-t)
 and I know if I include "Inner.h" in "main.cpp", the problem can be solved. But why?

For a raw pointer, I can simply use forward declearation in header file(`Outer.h`）, include implementation(`Inner.h`) in cpp file(`Outer.cpp`), delete it manully in destructor, and **no need to include implementation again whevever I use it.**

But for a unique_ptr, similarly I use forward declearation in header file(`Outer.h`）, include implementation(`Inner.h`) in cpp file(`Outer.cpp`), delete it automatically in destructor(with default destructor), **But why do I need to include inner class's implementation(`Inner.h`) again when I use it?**

Comment: The linked question explains it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is std::unique\_ptr<T> required to know the full definition of T?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012157/is-stdunique-ptrt-required-to-know-the-full-definition-of-t)

Comment: Calling `Bag::~Bag()` will call `std::unique_ptr<goods>::~unique_ptr`, which requires `goods` to be a complete type as it might call `goods::~goods()` (even though it doesn't actually call it as the pointer is `nullptr`, it is still required by the standard. With raw pointers you still have to construct and destruct at the memory pointed to). This is in the table provided by the answer to that question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6089065/5754656: The destructor for `std::unique_ptr<T>` requires a complete definition for `T`.

Comment: @Artyer thanks for you kind explanation. But I think I have already implemented destruction of `Bag` in "Bag.cpp", so I don't need to include "goods.h" again in "main.cpp" or wherever I call "~Bag()`, do I?

Comment: @Artyer, in the other word, if i use a raw pointer instead of a unique_ptr, and delete `m_ptr` in ~Bag() manually, it's obviously I do not need to include "goods.h" again in "main.cpp" while `Bag` can be destructed properly. So why a unique_ptr need?

Comment: Thanks @LightnessRacesinOrbit , But the explanation in the link didn't solve my question. Some more details are put in my replied comments above.

Comment: If the detailed explanation there did not adequately explain it, you will have to tell us what is missing, lest we simply repeat ourselves.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I've edit my question to clarify my question. Thanks for your kind advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the constructor in the .cpp file, not just the destructor.

If the `Outer` constructor fails, it will need to destroy `m_ptr`, that that requires knowing the definition of `class Inner`.

Comment: I've tried to add a constructor for `Outer` but failed again.

Comment: @fateflame: It's the correct solution.  If it's still not working please post the full, exact content of the latest files you're having trouble with.

Comment: Thanks a lot John. I added a default constructor in the definition of class and failed(I know it's my fault XD). And when I move the implementation of constructor to cpp file, it succeed. Now I understand why compiler always complain about missing complete definiation of class `Inner` .Thank you!