# How to include twice a header that has static variable definitions?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

OpenVPN is a giant header only 'library'. I created a library based on it, which consists of a `MyClass.h` file that has a class `MyClass` that uses the headers from OpenVPN. I compile this library as `libmy`.

The problem is that when I try to use `libmy` in another project, I'm forced to include `MyClass.h`, which in turn includes all of the OpenVPN headers. I don't need them, since `MyClass` **hides all OpenVPN-related things**. However, since OpenVPN headers have some static variables like `static int context_data_index` (defined AND declared in header, [here](https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn3/blob/bf9f309f6f81c8e8d9173b021118d360f6cb2011/openvpn/openssl/ssl/sslctx.hpp#L2074)), these variables get duplicate definitions when I try to compile my new project.

Let me explain the problem better. This is `MyClass.h`:

```
class MyClass {
public:
//lots of 'methods' that hide OpenVPN-related things. Users of these methods dont even know about OpenVPN


private:
//Users of MyClass do not need to know about this unique_ptr, but I'm forced to show it in `MyClass.h`, which is why I get duplicated definitions
#ifndef DO_NOT_INCLUDE_OPENVPN_HEADERS
        std::unique_ptr<OpenVPNClient> openVpnClient;
#endif
}
```

as you can see, the users of `MyClass` don't have to know anything about OpenVPN objects. I even tried to put an `#ifndef` clause that conditionally includes `std::unique_ptr<OpenVPNClient> openVpnClient;` when compiling `libmy` but does not include when compiling the library that uses `libmy`, but I got terrible undefined behaviour by doing that. I guess it's because a class must have the same number of objects with the same objects in both the `libmy` implementation and in my new library.

What can I do about this problem?

Comment: One solution to hiding the implementation detail is to use PIMPL. [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl)

Comment: ***I guess it's because a class must have the same number of objects with the same objects in both the libmy implementation and in my new library.*** You can't have 2 different declarations of the class.

Comment: You may be able to forward declare `OpenVPNClient`. The users of your class need not include the header. For this to work your destructor for `MyClass` needs to be defined in your translation unit. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012157/is-stdunique-ptrt-required-to-know-the-full-definition-of-t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012157/is-stdunique-ptrt-required-to-know-the-full-definition-of-t)

Comment: @drescherjm Can you make this an answer?

Answer (score 0):

One solution to not requiring the users of your class to directly include the OpenVPN headers is to forward declare `OpenVPNClient` in your header for `MyClass` like this:

```
class OpenVPNClient;
```

For this to work your destructor for `MyClass` needs to be defined in your translation unit. This could be as simple as adding the following line to your source file for MyClass:

```
MyClass::~MyClass() = default;
```

There is more info on how to do this and why it is needed here:

[Is std::unique_ptr<T> required to know the full definition of T?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012157/is-stdunique-ptrt-required-to-know-the-full-definition-of-t)

An alternate solution is to use `PIMPL` with your class and completely hide the `OpenVPNClient` from the header. There is information on how to use `PIMPL` here:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl

In your question you asked about a solution where you used an #ifdef to hide the usage of the `OpenVPNClient` to users of your class but define it when building your class:  ***I guess it's because a class must have the same number of objects with the same objects in both the libmy implementation and in my new library.*** You can't have 2 different definitions of the class. This will cause undefined behavior.

Comment: I am trying to find a better explanation for the last part but I am having a difficulty finding a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
namespace my_namespace
{
   #include "something.h"
}
```