# Returning a unique_ptr<T> . Concept clarification

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, copy-constructor, unique-ptr

While reading about boost unique_ptr and on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876751/differences-between-unique-ptr-and-shared-ptr) it states that such a pointer cannot be copied which I understand however it states that such a pointer can be returned from a function. This raises a question in my mind when something is returned from a function (not as a reference or a pointer) the copy constructor is called.So does this mean that unique ptr does not work with the assignment operator and works with a copy constructor (such that only ptr points to an object at a time) Also does it have less of an overhead than boost a shared_ptr ? I am using VS2010

Comment: "However, unique_ptr can be moved using the new move semantics". You should look into rvalue references in general and move semantics in particular.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning unique\_ptr from functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316727/returning-unique-ptr-from-functions)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> when something is returned from a function (not as a reference or a pointer) the copy constructor is called. [...]

Not necessarily. In C++11, the copy constructor is picked only if a *move constructor* is not present. In the absence of a move constructor, what would normally be a move (e.g. upon returning by value from a function) decays to a copy.

`unique_ptr` has a move constructor, which means a `unique_ptr` can be returned by value from a function.

> Also does it have less of an overhead than boost a shared_ptr ?

That's an unrelated question, but yes, it does have less overhead. In fact, `unique_ptr` is designed to be a *zero-overhead* RAII wrapper of a raw pointer that realizes unique ownership. Using a `unique_ptr` does not cause any loss in terms of performance nor in terms of memory consumption with respect to the use of a raw pointer.

Comment: The second part is perfect. Could you explain the first part in terms of C++0x

Comment: @MistyD: There is no "C++0x". C++0x is the name C++11 had before it was known that the Standard would be finalized in 2011

Comment: I am sorry I meant the old C++98

Comment: @MistyD: In C++98 there were no move semantics, so you couldn't return by value something that is non-copyable

Comment: So are you suggesting that a unique_ptr cannot be returned in C++98.

Comment: @MistyD: Yes, a `unique_ptr` cannot be returned by value in C++98. Also notice, that there was no `std::unique_ptr` in C++98.

Comment: Oh thanks. I thought Boost had an implementation turns out I was wrong. Will mark this as answer after timer

Comment: @MistyD: Boost has `scoped_ptr`, but in C++98 you cannot return it by value, since it's non-copyable

Comment: @MistyD: Does this answer your question?

Comment: Should we have something in the first paragraph about the returned thing being local to the function?

Comment: @aschepler: I would be glad to improve my answer, but I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Could you please elaborate a bit?