# How to use smart pointer wrap an array?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, smart-pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

Duplicate as [shared_ptr to an array : should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061979/shared-ptr-to-an-array-should-it-be-used)

---

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061979/shared-ptr-to-an-array-should-it-be-used), the good way to wrap a array with smart_ptr is to define a *deleter* function and pass the *deleter* function to smart_ptr alone with raw arrays.

---

I'm going to refactor my code, like wrap raw arrays with smart_ptr.
Here's a example:

Original codes:

```
    class MyList{
    public:
       MyList(int size = 0);
       void Resize(int size);
       ~MyList();
    private:
       int* myArray; 
       int* head_;
       size_t size_;
    }

    MyList::MyList(int size){
        myArray = new int[size]; //allocated memory when object is being created 
        head_ = list_;
        size_ = size;
    }

    void MyList::Resize(int size) {
        if (!list_) {
             delete myArray;
             size_ = 0;
        }
        myArray = new int[size];
        head_ = list_;
        size_ = size;
    }

    MyList::~MyList(){
       delete myArray;
       head = null_ptr;
    }
```

My question is: 
How to correctly wrap raw arrays with `smart_ptr`?

Comment: try `myArray = new myArraySize()`

Comment: I didn't get it, can you give me more details? Thank you

Comment: you have to build a new instance with the `new` operator, which means calling the constructor, which means `myArraySize()`, not `myArraySize`. Of course I'm assuming that `myArraySize` is a well defined `class` type.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061979/shared-ptr-to-an-array-should-it-be-used

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Don't use `shared_ptr` as your default smart pointer.

Thats [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). `shared_ptr` corresponds to shared ownership. You want unique ownership.

More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876751/differences-between-unique-ptr-and-shared-ptr).

---

#### Reassignment of smart pointers

Smart pointers are not assignable to raw pointers. That has good reasons.

Instead, write

```
myArray = std::make_shared<int>( myArraySize );
// Creates ONE int-object, which is initialized to myArraySize
```

Or use the initialization list directly:

```
myClass::myClass(int myArraySize) :
    myArray{ std::make_shared<int>(myArraySize) } {}
```

---

#### But you want an array!

Firstly, you should use `std::size_t` for specifying array bounds.

Now to the actual code for setting up the right smart pointer and initializing it:

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> myArray;

// [...]

myClass::myClass(int myArraySize) :
    myArray{ new int[myArraySize]() } {}
    // value-initialized it
```

Or since C++1y (or with an own definition) with [`make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique):

```
myClass::myClass(int myArraySize) :
    myArray{ std::make_unique<int[]>(myArraySize) } {}
```

Comment: my bad. Still, using `make_shared` is at least more efficient, even if not more correct...

Comment: @Deduplicator How is `make_shared` more efficient? It merely wrapps the call.

Comment: @CharlesChow Did you even read the rest of my post!?

Comment: Assignment of a raw pointer to a shared pointer without giving a referenced other shared_ptr allocates a new reference-count+deleter object. `make_shared` combines this allocation with the payload allocation.

Comment: it looks like myArray.reset(new int[myArraySize]) is working, I'm using LLVM5.1

Comment: Here's what I did, std::unique_ptr<int[]> myArray; myArray.reset(new int[10]); and it's working, I just re assigned size 10 to myArray, did I do something bad?

Comment: @CharlesChow No, it's fine, nevermind. Just try to use `make_unique`.

Comment: @Deduplicator Correct, according to the standard. Thanks, edited.