# Equivalent of pointer in smart pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

I am new to pointers, so consider the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    double xNormal{5};
    double * pNormal = &xNormal;
    xNormal = 10;
    std::cout<<"value of variable we are pointing to is : "<<*pNormal<<std::endl;
        
    double xSmart{5};
    std::unique_ptr<double> pSmart = std::make_unique<double>(xSmart);
    xSmart = 10;
    std::cout<<"value of variable we are pointing to through a smart pointer is : "<<*pSmart<<std::endl;
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
value of variable we are pointing to is : 10
value of variable we are pointing to through a smart pointer is : 5
```

In this code, if we use normal pointers and we change the value of the original variable, the dereferenced pointer also "tracks" the value because it's pointing towards that memory location.

When it comes to smart pointers, I noticed that there is no such "tracking", maybe I am doing a mistake in understanding but the question is, what is the equivalent of `double * pNormal = &xNormal;` in smart pointers?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: This code appears to be working *against* what a smart pointer does. 
 You could do `std::unique_ptr<double> pSmart(&xSmart);` ... but then you'll run into problems when `pSmart` gets destructed, because it does not actually **own** the underlying `xSmart` (automatic storage scope owns it).  It'd need to `pSmart.release()` before being destructed.

Comment: You're incorrectly expecting `std::make_unique<double>(xSmart)`  to create a smart pointer that directly manages (or refers to, or points to) `xSmart`.   The created smart point manages a (dynamically allocated) `double` that is distinct from `xSmart`, but is initialised to have the same value as `xSmart`.  Strip out the use of smart pointers, and your code is effectively doing `double xSmart{5}; double * pSmart = new double{xSmart}; xSmart = 10; std::cout << *pSmart;  delete pSmart;`.  In my version, compare the addresses `&xSmart` and `pSmart` and they will have different values

Comment: I personally think it's a good idea to not think of the "smart pointers" as pointers at all, but as objects with special ideas about ownership.

Comment: It is still `*pSmart = 10;` to assign a value in that sense the usage is not different from a raw pointer. But as @molbdnilo says, you describe intent. With std::unique_ptr you say there is only one owner of the pointer (the code that needs to free up the memory later).

Comment: So the big gain is when you have a function returning a raw pointer. With a raw pointer return value, there is always confusion (without reading documentation) who has to cleanup the memory. Not so with std::unique_pointer, and you can also pass on "ownership" to other parts of the code (learn about move semantics for that).

Comment: Welcome to C++. Don't rush into pointers. More importantly don't use raw pointers anywhere in your code. There's a lot more to learn, before getting lost in the dark woods by following pointers. Be smart ; don't do that.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> std::unique_ptr<double> pSmart = std::make_unique<double>(xSmart);
> ```

This line creates a *new* pointer that contains the value that `xSmart` has at the time of the call. It doesn't create a pointer to an existing variable.

You **would not want** to use `std::unique_ptr::reset()`.

```
std::unique_ptr<bar> pointer;
pointer.reset(&xSmart);
```

[How to assign the address of an existing object to a smart pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28502067/)

because it will `delete` on destruction something local, as the referred answer says. You don't want `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` around automatic (stack) objects.

Comment: "You 'd need `std::unique_ptr::reset`." No, as, as you mention, it would do an invalid `delete`. **If** you provide hack, provide all stuff with `release()`, but better just don't provide hack.

Answer (score 1):

What `std::make_unique<double>(xSmart)` does:

0. Allocates `sizeof(double)` of heap memory and assigns the given **value** to it, as if it called `new double{xSmart}`.
1. Returns a `std::unique_ptr<double>` pointing at the new memory. The smart pointer, in its destructor, will `delete` the allocated memory once it goes out of scope.
2. Therefore a `std::unique_ptr` should **never** point at heap memory, as in `std::unique_ptr<double>{&xSmart}`, because its later attempt at a `delete` would cause a crash and/or arbitrary undefined behavior.

In summary, there is no reference to `xSmart` in the `pSmart` pointer. The value from `xSmart` was copied to a new, dynamically allocated `double`. Below are a few examples, both good and bad.

0. Just a style recommendation / opinion: Prefer references over pointers which always point at something existing, i.e. should not hold a `nullptr`.
1. **Don’t try this at home.** In [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) you can find out that a custom `Deleter` class can be supplied to a `std::unique_ptr`. Which is what we do here. And the deleter does **nothing**. That way you can construct a “smart” (*dumbed down*, actually) pointer that points at a heap location and doesn’t wreak havoc. Needless to say that this is utterly useless and confusing at best.
2. This is loosely based on your dynamic, smart pointer case. First we dynamically allocate a `double` and assign `5` to it. Then we take an old school pointer to the `double`. Then we assign it through the pointer and check if the pointed-at location (on the heap) really changed. And yes, it did. This time we use `std::default_delete<double>`, i.e. the template’s default `Deleter`, which `delete`s the allocated heap memory when `main()` ends and `pUselessSmart`’s destructor runs.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main() {
  // Example 0: A local reference to a double on the stack.
  double xNormal{5};
  double &rNormal{xNormal};
  xNormal = 10;
  std::cout << "value of variable we are pointing to is : " << rNormal
            << std::endl;

  // Example 1: A “smart” pointer pointing at a double on the stack.
  double xSmart{5};
  std::unique_ptr<double, void (*)(double *)> pSmart{&xSmart, +[](double *) {}};
  xSmart = 10;
  std::cout
      << "value of variable we are pointing to through a dumb pointer is : "
      << *pSmart << std::endl;

  // Example 2: A smart pointer pointing at a heap-allocated double.
  std::unique_ptr<double> pUselessSmart{std::make_unique<double>(5)};
  double *qUselessSmart{pUselessSmart.get()};
  *qUselessSmart = 10;
  std::cout
      << "value of variable we are pointing to through a smart pointer is : "
      << *pUselessSmart << std::endl;
}
```

One key flaw of my dumb “smart” pointer example above is poor code readability. By convention, a `std::unique_ptr` represents memory **ownership**. It may transfer ownership to other instances, possibly through `return`s and call sites, using R-value (`&&`) references and a corresponding copy-constructor and `operator =()` taking `&&` references (with `const &` counterparts `= delete`d). However, a `std::unique_ptr` should **not** point at something it doesn’t own, i.e. something it cannot / should not `delete`, such as stack memory, memory owned by another `std::unique_ptr` (which would defy the `unique` in its name) etc.