# What is the rationale for the difference in destruction behavior between std::unique_ptr and std::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++14

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr:

> If `T` is derived class (*sic*) of some base `B`, then `std::unique_ptr<T>` is
>   implicitly convertible to `std::unique_ptr<B>`. The default deleter of
>   the resulting `std::unique_ptr<B>` will use operator delete for `B`,
>   leading to undefined behavior unless the destructor of `B` is virtual.
>   Note that `std::shared_ptr` behaves differently: `std::shared_ptr<B>` will
>   use the operator delete for the type `T` and the owned object will be
>   deleted correctly even if the destructor of `B` is not virtual.

What is the rationale for the difference in behavior upon destruction that is described above? My initial guess would be performance?

Also interesting to know is how an `std::shared_ptr<B>` is able to call the destructor of a type `T` in case the destructor on `B` is non-virtual and can not be called as far as I can see from the context of `std::shared_ptr<B>`?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876751/differences-between-unique-ptr-and-shared-ptr

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::shared_ptr<X>` already has a bunch of overhead over a raw `B*`.

A `shared_ptr<X>` basically maintains 4 things.  It maintains a pointer-to-`B`, it maintains two reference counts (a "hard" reference count, and a "soft" one for `weak_ptr`), and it maintains a cleanup function.

The cleanup function is why `shared_ptr<X>` behaves differently.  When you create a `shared_ptr<X>`, a function that calls that particular type's destructor is created and stored in the cleanup function managed by the `shared_ptr<X>`.

When you change types managed (`B*` becomes `C*`), the cleanup function remains unchanged.

Because `shared_ptr<X>` needs to manage the reference counts, the extra overhead of that cleanup function storage is marginal.

For a `unique_ptr<B>`, the class is almost as cheap as a raw `B*`.  It maintains zero state other than its `B*`, and its behavior (at destruction) boils down to `if (b) delete b;`.  (Yes, that `if (b)` is redundant, but an optimizer can figure that out).

In order to support cast-to-base and delete-as-derived, extra state would have to be stored that remembers the `unique_ptr` is *really* to a derived class.  This could be in the form of a stored pointer-to-deleter, like a `shared_ptr`.

That would, however, double the size of a `unique_ptr<B>`, or require it to store data on the heap somewhere.

It was decided that `unique_ptr<B>` should be zero-overhead, and as such it doesn't support cast-to-base while still calling base's destructor.

Now, you can probably teach `unique_ptr<B>` to do this by simply adding a deleter type and storing a destruction function that knows the type of thing it is destroying.  The above has been talking about the default deleter of `unique_ptr`, which is stateless and trivial.

```
struct deleter {
  void* state;
  void(*f)(void*);
  void operator()(void*)const{if (f) f(state);}
  deleter(deleter const&)=default;
  deleter(deleter&&o):deleter(o) { o.state = nullptr; o.f=nullptr; }
  deleter()=delete;
  template<class T>
  deleter(T*t):
    state(t),
    f([](void*p){delete static_cast<T*>(p);})
  {}
};
template<class T>
using smart_unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, deleter>;

template<class T, class...Args>
smart_unique_ptr<T> make_smart_unique( Args&&... args ) {
  T* t = new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  return { t, t };
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c191d82db157f143), where I generate a unique-ptr to derived, store it in a unique-ptr to base, and then reset base.  The derived pointer is deleted.

( A simple `void(*)(void*)` deleter might run into problems whereby the passed in `void*` would differ in value between the base and derived cases. )

Note that changing the pointer stored in such a `unique_ptr` without changing the deleter will result in ill advised behavior.

Comment: Good answer, but `unique_ptr` is not really zero-overhead in the general case. It has to store a deleter too. Unlike `shared_ptr`, though, the deleter type is part of its type (through a template parameter). For zero-size deleters, zero-overhead is indeed possible through empty base optimisation.

Comment: @Angew I always forget if it does the if test or not.  I do think I've seen an implementation that does the wrong thing there.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid I have added a smarter unique ptr, simply using the 2nd parameter deleter, that stores what is to-be-deleted.  It has way more overhead than a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: The `if(b)` part is important for custom deleters that can't handle nulls. Also, a `std::function` is a bad deleter - its constructors can throw.

Comment: @T.C. agreed.  Light weight two-pointer `deleter` written.  Do not think we can do this stateless, because determining how to delete `derived` from `base` basically requires a second pointer.  Hmm, maybe through careful use sub-typed deleters, where `unique_ptr< base, deleter<base> >`  records `void* -> base -> derived` then delete?  Basically keep track of how the cast-to-base changed the `void*` and unroll.  Tricky.

Comment: @BenVoigt it had fewer `<T>` clauses at the time angew commented.  I fixed it in response to his comment.

Comment: Aside: am now convinced that stateless is not just tricky, but impossible in general.