# How to delete linked list using free

Tags: c++, c, list, free

i've got these structures:

```
typedef struct tStimulus_tc
{
    short                Key;
    struct tStimulus_tc *Next;

}Stimulus_tc;

struct Frame_tc
{
    int                   ID;     // Frame ID (0..MAX)
    int                   Count;  // Felt Count
    short                 sSize;  // Stimulus List Size
    Stimulus_tc          *sList;  // Stimulus List

};
```

if i want to free a "struct Frame_tc" is this enough?

```
void freeFrame (Frame_tc *fTemp)
{
    free(fTemp);
}
```

or i need to run throught it's stimulus and free 1 by 1?
what's the proper way to free a variable?

Comment: For every `malloc`, there should be exactly one `free`.

Comment: If this is a C++ question you should be using `new` and `delete`, not `malloc()` and `free()`. Or better still a collection.

Comment: Why is this marked C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`free()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) takes a previously allocated block and releases it for reuse. It doesn't know nor care about the contents of the buffer.

While you could write a compiler that recursively frees pointers, this isn't a good idea:

```
static Stimulus_tc stim;
Frame_tc *fTemp = malloc(sizeof *fTemp);
fTemp->sList = &stim;
fTemp->sSize = 1;
free(fTemp); // if this recursively freed pointers, we would free a static object
```

Only you know how your structure is constructed, therefore you shoud be the one destructing it. In your case that means walking the linked list and freeing each member.

In C++, it's advisable to use higher level mechanisms, like using a [`std::vector<Stimulus_tc>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::list<Stimulus_tc>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list).

In cases where pointer use is inevitable (your case isn't one), consider using [smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876751/differences-between-unique-ptr-and-shared-ptr). And if you absolutely must manage memory the old way, [use type-safe `new[]`/`delete[]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-vs-new).

Comment: Thanks :) very helpfull

Comment: @user3728181 I had overlooked that `sList` is a linked list. I adjusted the answer accordingly. David's answer shows how to free a linked list.

Answer (score 2):

In C, if your `Stimulus_tc` list within the `struct Frame_tc` wrapper is not a traditional head/tail list (e.g. with the final `->Next = NULL`), but with the number of nodes contained in `list->sSize`, you could do something similar to the following:

```
/* free all nodes in struct Frame_tc->Stimulus_tc list */
void free_list (struct Frame_tc *list)
{

    Stimulus_tc *iter = list->sList;    /* pointer to iterate list   */
    Stimulus_tc *victim = NULL;         /* pointer to node to delete */
    int n = list->sSize;                /* number of nodes to delete */

    if (iter ==  NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr,"print_list() warning: empty list.\n");
        return;
    }

    while (n--) {       /* free n nodes */
        victim = iter;
        iter = iter->Next;
        free (victim);
    }
}
```

If you set the final `Next` pointer to `NULL`, you can eliminate `int n = list->sSize;` and simply iterate over the list with `while (iter) { ...`

If there were additional pointer elements within each node that were allocated, you would simply `free` those values before `free (victim);`

Look it over and let me know if you have any questions.